# use awk to search for match and rename

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk, match

I'm breaking my head trying to find a solution to this and hope someone can help. I have two files...  File1 contains a long list of unique strings coding for some sample sequence (single column). File2 contains many records and many columns, but here the records organize unique strings that have matching sample sequences. I want AWK to search for each unique string from File1 in File2, and rename the unique string in File1 with the string found in $1 of File2 corresponding to the record where the unique string was found.

**File1**

```
id1
id2
id3
id4
id5
id6
id7
id8
id9
id10
```

**File2**

```
id1,id9,id33,id35,id36,id37,id76
id5,id7,id8,id20,id22,id23
id6,id11,id13,id14
```

**Desired Output**

```
id1
id2
id3
id4
id5
id6
id5
id5
id1
id10
```

My actual File1 has about 17,000 records in $1 and File2 has about 4,000 records, with 1-400 fields. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different way to awk it.  Put the following into an executable awk file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

FNR==NR {f1[$0]=NR; out[NR]=$0; cnt=NR; next}

{
split($0, f2_line, ",")
for( fld in f2_line ) {
    f1_line_num=f1[f2_line[fld]]
    if( f1_line_num!="" ) out[f1_line_num]=f2_line[1]
    }
}

END { for( j=1;j<=cnt;j++ ) print out[j] }
```

If you call the executable awk file `awko`, you'd run it like `awko file1 file2`.  Yields the desired output from the inputs shown in the question.

The breakdown:

- Make two arrays of file1, one keyed by unique id( `f1` ), the other by line number( `out` ).
- Parse each line in file2 into an array( `f2_line` )
- For each field in `f2_line`, check if there's a line number in `f1` and set it to `f1_line_num`.
- If `f1_line_num` is non-empty, replace the corresponding entry in `out`.
- At the `END`, print `out` in line number order.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for the breakdown. Making an array from file2 for recursive search was genius!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, though I'd like to point out that no recursion is happening.  `file2` is being examined in order, line-by-line and fields in each line are compared to the associative array made from `file1`.  By contrast, @JS웃 s answer is putting `file2` into an array and examining `file1` line-by-line which means that answer wouldn't need an `out` array like mine is using to preserve `file1`'s output order.  Both of our answers `split()` the lines from `file2` but use different sources to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Awk I dunno.  Sed?

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/s;\\(\2\\);\1;/' File2 | sed 's/,/\\|/g' > temp.sed
sed -f temp.sed File1 > Desired
```

Comment: This worked great for the example file but not for the large files I am working with. I'm not familiar with sed at all (new to programming really), but I think it didn't work because not all the records for file 2 have multiple fields so some of the records are left without the `s;\(|id#\);id#;` pattern? This is the error I get `sed: 1: temp.sed: unterminated substitute pattern`

Comment: sed just does ordinary search-and-replace.  Probably one of your fields has a semi-colon, which I am using as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
  lines[$0]++;
  next
}
{
  for(line in lines) {
    num = split(line, flds, /,/);
    for(i=1; i<=num; i++) {
      if(flds[i] == $1) {
        print flds[1]; next
      }
    }
  }
  print $1; next
}' file2 file1
id1
id2
id3
id4
id5
id6
id5
id5
id1
id10
```

- We first scan the file2 and store entire lines from file2 in an array called `lines` as key
- Once file2 is stored completely we move to file1.
- For each line in our `lines` array, we split the line with `,` as delimiter and store the values from line in a `flds` array
- We iterate through our `flds` array. If we find a matching value in our array to our column1 from file1 we print the first element of our array (that is column1 from file2).
- If we don't find a match after scanning all lines we just print the column1 from file1 as is.

Comment: This code worked great for the example I posted but when I ran it with the actual large files it printed non-stop output. It may have printed all the iterations and not just the replaced output from file1. Not sure what went on, I had to interrupt the run.

Comment: Notice the order in which files are passed. Put file2 before file1.